# Create custom rules with params through API

Tags: api, post, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I'm trying to create a XPath custom rule with the Sonar API, but I have an issue when adding the parameters.

Here is my HTTP request :

```
    http.sendPostRequest("http://localhost:9000/api/rules/create" 
            + "?custom_key=test" 
            + "&markdown_description=test" 
            + "&name=test"
            + "&params=expression=test;filePattern=test;message=test" 
            + "&severity=BLOCKER" 
            + "&template_key=xml:XPathCheck");
```

I receive a code 200 and the rule is created in Sonar, except the parameters "params" are empty.

I've checked the API's documentation, it says it should be something like "params=key1=v1;key2=v2", it meets this format but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use a key that was already used by another key, even when this rule is removed.
You need to add the parameter prevent_reactivation=true in order to fail if a rule already exists with this key.

Comment: Thanks! But still, is there a way to override/erase the removed rule? Maybe with POST update?

Comment: No, nothing can be done on removed rules. You need to use another key if the one you've chosen already exist.

Answer (score 1):

So, I find out that if you create a new rule with the same key than a previously deleted rule, it recovers its parameters.

For my case, I've tried to create a rule with the key "test", but before this, I create and delete a rule "test" with no parameters. It seems that Sonar have some sort of cache.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this bug, which version of SonarQube are you using ?

Comment: It's very strange, because of 4.5.6, I've tried to create a custom rule 'test', delete it, and re-create it and I've the following message "A rule with the same key has been previously deleted. Please reactivate the existing rule or modify the key to create a new rule.".

Comment: I'm creating rules with the Sonar API, not through the web application. I'm sending POST request with HTTP to the API.

Comment: Indeed you're right ! In 4.5.6, when you create a custom rule using the WS with the same key than a previously deleted one, it reactivated the removed rule. That's probably why it was forbidden to do this operation in the UI.

Comment: To prevent this, you need to add the parameter prevent_reactivation=true when creating a new custom rule, to prevent reactivating an existing rule. (An error 409 will be returned)